# Split dynamic CSV file into 3 separate files using Bash script with either Awk, Sed, Grep, etc

Tags: bash, csv, awk, sed, grep

i have seen similar questions all over but none seems close to what i'm trying to achieve.

I have a dynamic csv file (tab delimiter) that updates/gets appended each hour **BUT NOTE:** Only the number of rows underneath ***HEADER 1*** and ***HEADER 2*** increases every hour. Pls see two examples below as reference

Example of FileA.csv **at the 3rd hour**

```
HEADER 1 NUM
hour 1   5
hour 2   10
hour 3   15
HEADER 2 NUM
hour 1   3
hour 2   6
hour 3   9
HEADER 3 NUM
age      23
bus      21
pig      07
dog      40
```

Example of FileA.csv **at the 7th hour**

```
HEADER 1 NUM
hour 1   5
hour 2   10
hour 3   15
hour 4   20
hour 5   25
hour 6   30
hour 7   35
HEADER 2 NUM
hour 1   3
hour 2   6
hour 3   9
hour 4   12
hour 5   15
hour 6   18
hour 7   21
HEADER 3 NUM
age      13
bus      28
pig      85
dog      55
```

The rows underneath Header 1 and Header 2 increases each hour. Header 3 and below is the only thing that remains constant

So what i'm trying to achieve is simply separate FileA.csv into ABC.csv , DEF.csv , GHI.csv

using the 3rd hour example for reference to what i'm trying to achieve

ABC.csv

```
HEADER 1 NUM
hour 1   5
hour 2   10
hour 3   15
```

DEF.csv

```
HEADER 2 NUM
hour 1   3
hour 2   6
hour 3   9
```

GHI.csv

```
HEADER 3 NUM
age      23
bus      21
pig      07
dog      40
```

Below is what i tried to do using grep but i can't combine grep and cut to achieve this. I've tried using Sed but not sure how to cut and move it after searching. i know this can be achieved with awk but not strong in awk

1. First cut out HEADER 3 and subsequent rows below and putting that into GHI.csv since that will always be constant, that way we are left with HEADER 1 and HEADER 2.
2. Then cut out HEADER 2 and below by searching for the Header name and cutting it out with all subsequent rows beneath it
3. Finally we are left with HEADER 1 which we either leave in FileA.csv or move it to ABC.csv

Pls Help. Thanks

Comment: _Header 3 and below is the only thing that remains constant_: The examples you show contradict this statement. After 7 hours the `HEADER 3 NUM` block is not the same as after 3 hours.

Comment: From the answers you received, were you able to do what you wanted to do? I am surprised that this question was closed. It seemed like a straightforward and clear question to me.

Comment: @zedfoxus not yet. i'm currently editing the question and i will re-post it. Hopefully it's more straightforward and focused

Answer (score 2):

With any `awk` and any number of text blocks:

```
awk '/^HEADER/ {n++} {print>("File" n ".csv")}' FileA.csv
```

We simply increment variable `n` (initialized to 0, by default) each time a line starts with `HEADER`, we print all lines with redirection to a file named `Filen.csv`.

Note: if other lines can also start with `HEADER` you can be more specific about the header regex (e.g., `/^HEADER [[:digit:]]+ NUM$/`).

The output file names are `File1.csv`, `File2.csv`, ... If you absolutely want `ABC.csv`, `DEF.csv`, `GHI.csv` you can use:

```
awk -v f="ABC.csv DEF.csv GHI.csv" '
  BEGIN {split(f,files)} /^HEADER/ {n++} {print>files[n]}' FileA.csv
```

Explanations:

- We pass the space-separated list of file names as variable `f`.
- We split it on spaces and store it in array `files`.
- When printing, instead of redirecting to file `Filen.csv` we redirect to entry number `n` of `files` array.

Note that if you have more text blocks than listed files you will get an error when the array index overflows.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the headers literally have "HEADER ..." lines as described,
would you please try:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {                     # define filenames to write
        fname[1] = "ABC.csv"; fname[2] = "DEF.csv"; fname[3] = "GHI.csv"
    }
    /^HEADER/ {                 # reached the header line
        if (c >= 1) close(file) # close the previous file, if opened
        file = fname[++c]       # update the filename to write
    }
    {
        print > file            # append to the file
    }
' FileA.csv
```

Btw the fact the file is growing seems to be unrelated with
file splitting.

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like this. You won't need awk, sed, or grep. Bash itself can do this for you.

## test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE=FileA.csv

OUTPUT=ABC.csv
while read CMD; do
    
    if [[ "$CMD" == HEADER*1*NUM ]]; then
    OUTPUT=ABC.csv
    elif [[ "$CMD" == HEADER*2*NUM ]]; then
    OUTPUT=DEF.csv
    elif [[ "$CMD" == HEADER*3*NUM ]]; then
    OUTPUT=GHI.csv
    fi

    echo "$CMD" >> $OUTPUT

done < "$FILE"

echo "Done"
```

## Let's run it

```
chmod 755 test.sh
./test.sh
```

## Resulting files

ABC.csv

```
HEADER 1 NUM
hour 1   5
hour 2   10
hour 3   15
```

DEF.csv

```
HEADER 2 NUM
hour 1   3
hour 2   6
hour 3   9
```

GHI.csv

```
HEADER 3 NUM
age      23
bus      21
pig      07
dog      40
```

## Explanation

We loop through each line of the file. If we see HEADER 1 NUM, we say that the lines should be written to ABC.csv. If the line has HEADER 2 NUM, we say that the lines should be written to DEF and so on.

Then we write the lines to the respective file.

For example

- We read the first line. It has HEADER 1 NUM, which matches the regular expression HEADER*1*NUM. So, we say that the output file should be ABC.csv
- Then, we echo the line (stored in CMD variable) and send it to the output file, which we said was ABC.csv. The `>>` means append to ABC.csv file. So, HEADER 1 NUM gets written to that file
- Then, we read the 2nd line. None of the if..elif..elif..fi statements match the next line. So, the next line is echo'ed and appended to ABC.csv
- 3rd line - same thing
- When the line with HEADER 2 NUM appears, the 1st elif meets that criteria and the output file is changed to DEF.csv
- The HEADER 2 NUM line is written to DEF.csv
- The line following that is written to DEF.csv
- That keeps on going until the HEADER 3 NUM line matches the 2nd elif. That's when the output file changes to GHI.csv
- HEADER 3 NUM is written to GHI.csv
- Subsequent lines are also written to GHI.csv

If you want ABC, DEF, and GHI files to be removed, you can write `rm ABC.csv DEF.csv, GHI.csv` right before or after `FILE=FileA.csv` line in the script. That way, you are always getting brand new files.

Comment: Please copy/paste that script into http://shellcheck.net and read [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) and [correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)